# Selecting an element of a list inside a list (python)

Tags: python-3.x, list

Im attempting to write a turn based, pokemon-esque, game to test my python skills & learn new things.

I'm having trouble selecting an element from a list inside of another list.

```
Punch = ["Punch!", 20]
Kick = ["Kick!", 40]
Moves = [Punch, Kick]
Player = ["Jamie", 100, Moves]

print ("Do you want to punch, or kick?")
attack = input(" ")
if attack == "punch":
    atk = 0
if attack == "kick":
    atk = 1

damage = Player[2[atk[1]]]
print (Player[0]," uses ", Player[2[atk[0]]])
```

but this results in error:
    TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I understand why this error happens. But I'm wondering is there is another way to call up an element of a list inside of a list.

Thanks

Comment: `atk` is a variable not list as per the above code. So atk[1] is not a valid expression.

Comment: that's the problem. if attack = "punch" I want 
    damage = Player[2[0[1]]]
but if attack = "kick" I want 
    damage = Player[2[1[1]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably something like this :

```
damage = Player[2][atk][1]
```

But beware because you only define atk in if statements so atk could potentially not be defined after those ifs.

Moreover you place either 1 or 2 in atk but you only have two moves which makes me think you want to put either 0 or 1 in it.

Note: You should not capitalise the name of your variables as it would imply they are classes instead of variables

Answer (score 0):

from the way i understand

```
damage=Player[2][atk][1]
```

As has already been mentioned . The thing to understand is what is happening when you do this.

player[2] refers to Moves and when you further subscript it, it subscripts to the Moves, so player[2][atk] simply becomes Moves[atk].

A thing to keep in mind is that it is truly just a reference, if you were to change the list Moves, the value in player[2] will also change.

For example:
code:

```
Moves[1][2]=1000
print(player[2][1][2])
```

Will give output

```
1000
```